# OWIN SelfHosted in Windows Service Project Exception when installed in Windows Server

Tags: c#, .net, owin

I have a Winodws Service Solution that works fine in a Windows 10, but it does not start in a Windows Server 2012R2 or a Windows Server 2018

If I seek in Windows Events I get this FileNotFoundExceptionError:

Aplicación: ServicioWindowsPrueba.exe
Versión de Framework: v4.0.30319
Descripción: el proceso terminó debido a una excepción no controlada.
Información de la excepción: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback(System.Action`2<System.Type,System.Type>) en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.DoCallback(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>, System.Action`2<System.Type,System.Type>) en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServicesFactory.Create(System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2<System.String,System.String>, System.Action`1<Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.Services.ServiceProvider>)
en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.BuildServices(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)
en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start(Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.StartOptions)
en Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.WebApp.Start[System.__Canon, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
en RestOwin.RestOwinServidor.Start()
en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
en System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
en System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

this is my Startup class:

```
using Owin;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace RestOwin
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // This code configures Web API. The Startup class is specified as a type
        // parameter in the WebApp.Start method.
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
        {
            // Configure Web API for self-host. 
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}"
            //routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
            //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            appBuilder.UseWebApi(config);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my Server Class:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Owin.Hosting;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace RestOwin
{
    public class RestOwinServidor
    {
        //Puerto de escucha
        public int port { get; set; }

        public void Start()
        {

            //try
            //{

            string baseAddress = "http://127.0.0.1:" + port + "/";

            // Start OWIN host 
            WebApp.Start<Startup>(url: baseAddress);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is solved. It was my fault, I was only copying the .dll an .exe file to Windows Server and I left the rest of the files that are also important